# echo the directory with the information

Tags: scripting

The following script is working, I would like one more piece of information to the result.  Besides the service `rtvscand` status, I also want to add where the file resides.  Like:
the symantec file resides in the /app directory or the symantec file resides in the /opt.

```
# cat /app/scripts/symantec_scripts/symantec.sh
for i in `cat /app/scripts/symantec_scripts/list`
do ssh root@$i "uname -n
if [ -s /app/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat ]; then
  cat /app/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat
else
  cat /opt/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat
fi
echo `service rtvscand status`
echo ....................................................................." ; done | tee /tmp/symantec_info.`date +"%m%d%y"`
```

Answer (score 3):

**PLEASE SEE MY OTHER (BETTER) ANSWER BELOW**

Add a variable `loc` to the if statement.

```
# cat /app/scripts/symantec_scripts/symantec.sh
for i in `cat /app/scripts/symantec_scripts/list`
do ssh root@$i "uname -n
  if [ -s /app/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat ]; then
    loc='/app'
    cat /app/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat
  else
    loc='/opt'
    cat /opt/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat
  fi
echo `service rtvscand status`
echo Location is $loc/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat
echo ....................................................................." ; done | tee /tmp/symantec_info.`date +"%m%d%y"`
```

EDIT
Changed `loc="string"` to `loc='string'` and removed double quotes from around the `echo` for printing the location.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried, it still does not give me the /opt or /app location.

Comment: server1
[DefDates]
LastDefs=20151006.003
CurDefs=20151007.001
rtvscand is running
Location is /Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat
.....................................................................
server2
[DefDates]
LastDefs=20151006.003
CurDefs=20151007.001
rtvscand is running
Location is /Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat

Comment: Can you post your version of the script again?  You should, at the very least, be able to add a string to "/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat" when you `echo` it.

Comment: for i in `cat /app/scripts/symantec_scripts/list`
do ssh root@$i "uname -n
if [ -s /app/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat ]; then
cat /app/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat
else
cat /opt/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat
fi
echo `service rtvscand status`
echo ....................................................................." ; done | tee /tmp/symantec_info.`date +"%m%d%y"`

Comment: Oh I see the problem.  Switch `loc="/opt"` and `loc="/app"` to `loc='/opt'` and `loc='/app'`.  I see you're using a double quote to send the entire paragraph of commands, so just use single quotes to capture the /opt or /app string.  I've updated my answer as well.

Comment: One more thing, you can simple remove double quotes from `echo "Location is $loc/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat"` to `echo Location is $loc/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat`, and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, I just tired it.  It still does not give the location like /app or /opt Please see the results

Comment: server1
[DefDates]
LastDefs=20151011.001
CurDefs=20151012.002
rtvscand is running
Location is /Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat
.....................................................................
server2
[DefDates]
LastDefs=20151010.019
CurDefs=20151011.001
rtvscand is running
Location is /Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat
.....................................................................
server3
[DefDates]
LastDefs=20151011.001
CurDefs=20151012.002
rtvscand is running
Location is /Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat
.....................................................................

Comment: I appreciate any information you share with me.

Comment: See my other answer.  I think it's better overall.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so since for some reason using a variable to store the location isn't working, I think a better method overall would be to use `find` to simply locate where Symantec exists, then you can `cat` it no problem and echo the whole path.

```
for i in `cat /app/scripts/symantec_scripts/list`
do ssh root@$i "uname -n
cat $(find / -maxdepth 2 -name Symantec)/virusdefs/definfo.dat
echo Location is $(find / -maxdepth 2 -name Symantec)/virusdefs/definfo.dat
echo ....................................................................."
done | tee /tmp/symantec_info.`date +"%m%d%y"`
```

Basically, `$(command)` will execute the command as if it were in shell and replace it with the output, so `$(find / -maxdepth 2 -name Symantec)` looks, starting in `/`, and only going down 2 directories in depth, for anything named Symantec, and outputs it.  This output is simply used in place of the whole $(command) statement.

The whole `$(find...)` statement in your case should output something like `/app/Symantec` or `/opt/Symantec`

This also has the added benefit of avoiding a lengthy `if` statement and locating Symantec if it happens to be anywhere else.

The only drawback is if for some reason you have more than one directory called Symantec in the immediate root directory and any directory a level above `/`.  This will cause problems.

Comment: Please edit you first answer with the one you consider is the best choice.